# Adding plugin to Webpack with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm using the Webpacker gem with Rails 5.2, and would like to access the environment in the Front End by setting a NODE_ENV global variable.
This is my config/webpack/environment.js file :

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// Bootstrap 3 has a dependency over jQuery:
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

I saw that I needed to add the following plugin to webpack to be able access the environment in the front-end :

```js
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
  })
```

But I don't know how to add it... I tried many options, including the line below and it always, either doesn't work, or break jQuery (i.e. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined) :

```js
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you just need to prepend/append a new plugin and give it a different name that those of your other plugins. Now my config/webpack/environment.js looks like that:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// Bootstrap 3 has a dependency over jQuery:
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)

environment.plugins.prepend('env',
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
  })
)


module.exports = environment
```

I can now access `NODE_ENV` from every js/jsx file !!

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51447443/2) to the question [Adding plugin to Webpack with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447443/adding-plugin-to-webpack-with-rails) by the OP [oruhtra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9591158/oruhtra) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>