# Rails 6 webpacker using environment variables in javascript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, dotenv

I want to use environment variables with my Rails 6 webpacker project in my js code follow this document https://webpacker-docs.netlify.app/docs/env

First, I create `.env` file at the root directory of my project.

Then

`config/webpack/environment.js` (I can access process.env just as expected from here)

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

const dotenvFiles = [
  `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.local`,
  '.env.local',
  `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  '.env'
]

dotenvFiles.forEach((dotenvFile) => {
  dotenv.config({ path: dotenvFile, silent: true })
})

environment.plugins.insert(
    "Environment",
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(process.env)
)

console.log(process.env) 
/* 
{
 .
 .
 .
 RAILS_ENV: 'development',
 MY_SECRET: 'This_is_my_secret',
 RACK_ENV: 'development',
 NODE_ENV: 'development'
}
*/

.
.
.

module.exports = environment
```

But when I run `console.log(process.env)` from `app/javascript/packs/application.js` I get empty object `{}` instead

I have tried these but have no luck.

1. Import and run `dotenv` again in `config/webpack/development.js`

```
// config/webpack/development.js
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config()
```

2. Change to use dotenv-webpack but the result is not difference.

**EDIT**

After searching for hours I found a workaround from this  [Adding plugin to Webpack with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447443/adding-plugin-to-webpack-with-rails)

For some reason if you run your rails server(`rails s`) with `bin/webpack-dev-server` your variables will be inaccessible.